# Try, Catch can't return correct value

Tags: c#, try-catch

This code aks for input from the user.

I wish to have the user try again after he sends wrong input and triggers any of the exceptions below.

After getInputNumber() is triggered after the exception and the user enters the right input as numbers, the return is then triggered which returns the correct number.

After this return, it returns to the FormatException thus deleting the correct number value and returning only 0.

How can I fix it to get the correct value, but also keep allowing the user to try again if he misses the correct input?

```
private static int getInputNumber()
        {
        int number = 0;

        try
        {
            number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is FormatException)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong format! \nTry numbers instead.");

                getInputNumber();

            }
            else if (ex is OverflowException)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("The number you entered is too large.\nTry a number between 1 and 2,147,483,647");
                getInputNumber();

            }
        }


        return number;
    }
```

Comment: Who calls `getInputNumber` method? Did you debug the code to figure out what exactly happens?

Comment: You need to write `number = getInputNumber();` in catch blocks.

Comment: Great! @ChetanRanpariya, you answer fixed it for me like I intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your catch block try this:

```
...
if (ex is FormatException)
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong format! \nTry numbers instead.");

   return getInputNumber();

}
....
```

Instead of just calling it. This is because when you call the getInputNumber() method after first catch and it passes successfull, it gets back to your catch block(at this point number is still 0 since a exception occurs)

As stybl said, it's better to use a boolean check and while loop to keep asking for a valid input user.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I recommend using [`Int32.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx) instead. It won't make much of a difference in this particular case, but it is considered best practice. For your code to work you need to include `return` statements for every recursive call of `getInputNumber`:

```
private static int getInputNumber()
{
    int number = 0;

    try
    {
        number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex is FormatException)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong format! \nTry numbers instead.");
            return getInputNumber();

        }
        else if (ex is OverflowException)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("The number you entered is too large.\nTry a number between 1 and 2,147,483,647");
            return getInputNumber();

        }
    }

    return number;
}
```

*However*, making `getInputNumber` recurse like that is a bad idea. Instead, you should use an infinite loop. The final result will look something like this:

```
private static int getInputNumber()
{
    int number = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            break;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is FormatException)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong format! \nTry numbers instead.");

            }
            else if (ex is OverflowException)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("The number you entered is too large.\nTry a number between 1 and 2,147,483,647");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Unexpected error!");
            }
        }
    }

    return number;
}
```

Comment: your answer @stybl also worked, but I had to throw in a boolean variable to make it work like you intended, unless I made some mistake. However, it also worked. Thanks

Comment: @jon Glad I could help. Be sure to mark the answer as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it solved your issue, and best of luck.